# Creating SQLite table with date as table name in Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Can we create `SQLite` database table with today's date as Table name? I have tried it but it throws error. Is there a way to create table with current date as table name?

My code is below:

> My Activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText et;
Button btn;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String date=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    final SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String str=et.getText().toString();
            if (str.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                try {
                    cv.put("name", str);
                    long insert=db.insert(date, null, cv);
                    if (insert!=-1){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (SQLiteException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> My `SQLiteOpenHelper` is

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String db_name="unitdb";
public static final int version=1;
Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, version);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

    db.execSQL("create table '"+date+"'(name TEXT)");
    Toast.makeText(context,"DB Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("dbcreate", "Database Created");
    Log.i("Table Created", "Bike Tracker Table Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion>=newVersion)

        return;

    if (oldVersion==1){

        Log.d("New Version","Data's can be Upgraded");

    }

    Log.d("Sample Data", "onUpgrade:" + newVersion);

}
```

}

> My Log cat is

```
06-29 17:19:03.802    1589-1589/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "29": syntax error
06-29 17:19:03.919      355-407/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
06-29 17:19:04.084    1589-1589/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting name=dai
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "29": syntax error (code 1): ,    while compiling: INSERT INTO Jun 29, 2015(name) VALUES (?)
        at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at com.realtech.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Why would you ever need a table that's called like today's date? I am willing to bet anything that this is an XY problem.

Comment: I get the date using `String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());` for example 29-Jun-2015

Comment: Did you read the comment I wrote or not? Why do you **need** the table named as today's date?

Comment: yes. I want to use today's date as table name

Comment: They say the third time is the charm - **why do you need table called as today's date?**

Comment: i need to save the incoming messages with some special character into my table everyday

Comment: I feel dumb now - what's that "special character" have to do with the table name? Why does the table name have to be equal to today's date? Why are you not reading?

Comment: I'm monitoring a tracker device fitted on a car which sends status message everyday to my mobile. now i want to store them in table to see the history everyday.

Comment: The date should be one of the columns in your table. Are you really going to want to manage, for examle, 365 different databases after 1 year? The reason you can't have the table name you show is that you have special characters in it, so you need to surround the table name with square brackets or backticks or whatever SQLite's escaping mechanism is. But, **please**, don't do this. You will find it completely unmanageable and error prone. Add a date as another column and insert your messages with said date.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I understand. A table for each day would be very difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is not valid identifier.
format it or perform string operations to come up with valid identifier.
don't start with number. don't use special character(underscore is allowed).
instead standard practice, create one table and add date field to it makes all current and previous data available to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

wrong in table creation, you need to change as follows.

```
db.execSQL("create table '"+date+"'(name TEXT)");
```

replace with,

```
String tableName="your_table";// give valid name only.
db.execSQL("create table "+tableName+"(name TEXT)");
```

Comment: table names with special character are not valid then?

Comment: if you want date as tablename then give tablename as Jun_29_2015. if you are giving spaces and commas(,) then it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape comma in your table name, try this:

```
String tab_name = date.replace(","\,");
```

and then use tab_name as name of you table